# How to pass message resource id to thymeleaf fragment

Tags: thymeleaf

How to pass message resource id to thymeleaf fragment

for example

```
<head th:replace="fragments/head-import :: head-shared('#{view.index.title}')"></head>
```

where *view.index.title* is an id in message resource file (Spring MVC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass just `'view.index.title'`, there are a couple of ways you can display it. For example, if you use variable name `title`:

```
<span th:text="#{${title}}" />
```

or

```
<span th:text="${#messages.msg(title)}" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Both solutions are perfect and working!